# 7-Zip command line -p switch is not working according to the help page

Tags: windows, command-line, encryption, compression, 7-zip

I want to be able to automate the encryption of the file type .pcapng in a Windows batch script. My current problem is that I get an error when extracting the encrypted file saying something along the lines "error. Wrong Password?"

My script code:

```
7z a -t7z captures.7z -pINSERTPASSWORDHERE -mhe *.pcapng
```

The compression works as expected and this format for the `-p` switch was taken from 7-Zip's help page. But again the set password does not work, giving the error described above. After some playing I managed to get the code below to work... However I don't want there to be a prompt for a password; I want the password set using the value in the script.

```
7z a -t7z captures.7z -p INSERTPASSWORDHERE -mhe *.pcapng
```

Comment: -psecret seems to work as advertised in the help file.

Comment: What prompt are you talking about? The only difference between the two commands is an added space.

Comment: There must be no space after the -p switch, otherwise the program will prompt for a password.

Comment: I realize that but it was the only way I could get a set password to work. I was more so wondering why -pInsertPassword wasn't letting me open any encrypted file.

Comment: To further clarify my actual password had a mix of letters of different case and numbers as well. After more testing it seems that it doesn't like a password unless its all characters or numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I was having issues with the `-p` also. I found that I had a special character in the password and it needed to be escaped.

If you have a comma (`,`) or a exclamation point(`!`) you would need to escape the character like this:

`,` would be `^,` and `!` would be `^!`

Look [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

To fully script-automate:

**Create:**

```
7z -mhc=on -mhe=on -pPasswordHere a %ZipDest% %WhatYouWantToZip%
```

**Unzip:**

```
7z x %ZipFile% -pPasswordHere
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39826601/3441182

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere about another user having password problems and their workaround was to use a ridiculously long password. I tried one that had 50+ characters and now the script seems to work. It just seems a bit counter-intuitive when the help page uses "secret" as an example password.

Comment: This was moved from the question to an answer on behalf of RazgrizNeedsHelp

Answer (score 0):

If you have an empty file, it will still decompress the empty file, and it will not ask for a password.